# How to frame up to basement exterior door

Tags: doors, basement

We have a basement exterior door flush with concrete foundation. The front of our bottom plate is about 9 inches away from foundation due to plumbing pipes. We do not want to move the door. We are trying to figure out how to do this. How do we create a "return" wall and attach to concrete? How do we add drywall without it touching the concrete? Attached are pics of our door and also an example of what we are thinking about. We are DIY so details would be really helpful.

What we want.......

[image]

Our door...

[image]

Another pic of our door...

[image]

Idea...how do we drywall this??

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Great question; I can't help, but I'm sure one of our experts can.

Comment: Thanks..still waiting for some ideas. So far only idea we have is to add j bead to end of drywall that will abut the concrete wall....